# Chat listview stop refreshing image views

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, lazy-loading

So the problem is 
1. We are using listView for chat application
2 . each time a chat is sent or rec we update the arrayList and update the adapter and do notifydatasetAdaper() for refreshing the list view.
3. So if we send 10 images in chat and then send 11th chat msg(let say text chtat) and then call notifydatasetadapter() in this case all the 10 images are refreshing.
4. So i need to stop this refreshing of images.
5. ListView must be refreshed without refreshing the images

So any idea how can i achieve this.. or may be m on the wrong path please show me the correct way of doing it.....!!!

I also tried using picaso but the library is conflicting with okhttp library ....!!!

Also this is the way i am showing the images

```
public class ImageFromSd extends AsyncTask<Object, Bitmap, Bitmap> {

        ImageView im;

        // int targetWidth = 200;
        // int targetHeight = 200;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                im = (ImageView) params[0];
                String path = (String) im.getTag();

                Log.d("ankit", "image path :::::" + path);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

                // bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new
                // FileOutputStream(
                // path));
                //
                // bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, targetWidth,
                // targetHeight, false);
            }
            // catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            // bitmap = null;
            // }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                bitmap = null;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                bitmap = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                bitmap = null;
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result != null) {
                im.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                im.setImageBitmap(result);

            }
        }

    }


and then calling it like this 
    im.setTag(items.get(i).getTextChat());
    new ImageFromSd().execute(im);
```

Comment: Please post code for listview and adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You have to refresh listview as any data updates within listview.

```
Secondly, the method you using for loading image is not good.

try this library to load remote or local image. it maintains cache automatically and very efficient for image loading.
```

Universal Image Loader
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: jatin I am refreshing the list view on gcm msg comming and loading images from loacal sd card i thing UIL will not help me from local sd card loading images

Comment: Yes, you can also load your sdcard images using this library.

Comment: You just need to pass path, no need to make bitmap, this will save your memory

Answer (score 0):

- I am not checking for the bitmap is already cached or not.
- Everytime when a imageView is passed to AsynTask, i am decoding from the path. Which is wrong.
- I shouuld LRUCache or DiskCache and store the bitmap in cache with the path as key.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html